# Get parent by its children in Django Queryset

Tags: python, django, model, django-2.0

I have this model:

```
Department(models.Model):
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=128)
    reference = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='reference')
```

As you see, each object of this model can have parent and conversely.

For example, these are department's objects:

```
id = 1 , title = 'dep 1' , reference_id = Null
id = 2 , title = 'dep 2' , reference_id = 1
id = 3 , title = 'dep 3' , reference_id = Null
id = 4 , title = 'dep 4' , reference_id = 1
id = 5 , title = 'dep 5' , reference_id = 3
id = 6 , tiltl = 'dep 6' , reference_id = 3
id = 7 , title = 'dep 7' , reference_id = 3
id = 8 , title = 'dep 8' , reference_id = 9
id = 9 , title = 'dep 9' , reference_id = Null
id = 10, title = 'dep 10', reference_id = 9
```

Now I want to get list of objects that has this condition: `Each parent by its children`. like this:

```
- dep 1 
    dep 2 
    dep 4 
- dep 3 
    dep 5
    dep 6
    dep 7
- dep 9
    dep 8 
    dep 10
```

How can I do that? (Can I create this list just with `Django ORM`?)

**Update**
This is my department levels:

```
Department_Level = (
    (1, 'headquarters'),
    (2, 'unit'),
    (3, 'center'),
)
level = models.IntegerField(choices=Department_Level,default=.Department_Level[2][0])
```

**And I want just level 2 and 3 in my list.**

Comment: I assume the hierarchy can go on forever? As in a department can belong to department that belongs to another.

Comment: It might be better to look at a package like [**`django-mptt`**](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) that implements utilites for tree-structures.

Comment: Hierarchy has 3 level.  @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I can't use this package on my project. (Company policy) @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: How do you want your data to be returned?

Comment: `Queryset` or `python list`. @crimsonpython24

Answer (score 0):

It may be works using [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/). Please try it.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg


# dept_id is root department id
dept_list = Department.objects.filter(id=dept_id).annotate(reference_list=ArrayAgg('department__reference'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get all objects

```
mapper = dict(Department.objects.values_list("id", "reference_id"))
```

This will result in a dict (child to parent)

```
{1: None, 2: 1, ...}
```

Convert it dict with parent to children

```
res = dict()
for child, parent in mapper.items():
     res.setdefault(parent, []).append(child)
```

Now you can construct a data structure over it however you like. You can also get the grandchildren by finding the children of all children of an item.

Best to construct a tree structure and write a class method which returns the tree with `res` as input.

Edit. To answer the question posted in comments to with regards to N levels, we can use a tree-structure instead of a normal dict, but we can still fetch all grand children upto any level with the current dict structure. Below code with the assumption that there are no circular relationships.

```
def get_all_grand_children(node_id, n_level) -> List:
    if n_level == 0:
         return []
    output = list()
    for child in res.get(node_id, []):
         output.append(child)
         output.extend(get_all_grand_children(child, n_level - 1)
    return output
```

Comment: How can I find out grandchildren or grandgrandchildren (for n level references) with your method? @vestronge

Comment: Edited the answer to add short snippet to fetch all grandchildren upto a certain level.